# Possessive of "which"

Tags: whose

Is it possible to use *whose* as the possessive form of *which*?

- *Based on classic films -- whose screenplays were mostly dramatic --*
  *Bordwell exposed his theory of the hero.*

Is that correct?

Comment: This is commonly how it's done informally, yes.

Comment: By the way, it's possessive with four s's.

Comment: I deleted my answer since examples to the contrary were provided. It still feels wrong to me despite the attestations, but I don't want to muddy the waters for the OP. A style guide may provide better guidance than historic examples, though.

Comment: @Avangion: there are some dialects which only use *whose* for people, but this is not the case for standard English grammar.

Comment: Well I'm all for broad usage being more important than rules. I suppose there's a reason it feels wrong to me, but then the diversity of the language is what likely makes these sorts of questions so hard to answer. Even "standard" is hard to pinpoint exactly. The American Heritage Dictionary has a panel of experts who up or down vote these things and then you're informed of the percentages. I don't know what it is for this one, but I'm sure it's in there. I would be a down voter, I guess.

Comment: @Robusto: This is commonly how it's done formally, too. There's nothing "informal", "common", "impolite", or "incorrect" about this. It's like knowing that the possessive of the personal pronoun _he_ is the personal pronoun _his_; in this case, the possessive of the relative pronoun _which_ is the relative pronoun _whose_. No gender is expressed or implied by either relative pronoun, though Neuter is the best way to bet.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yeah, I figured. My comment was just a drive-by because I'm at work and I was hedging my bets against the possibility that legions of Fowler-brandishing users were going to lay about me with truncheons.

Comment: @Robusto: Come, we're armoured with righteousness; the Peeververein shall not triumph.

Comment: So, to partially vindicate myself, I looked up the usage note I knew just had to exist on this point. I guessed the result would be 60-40 or so in favor of you guys, that whose is OK to use to refer to inanimate objects. Turns out I was quite close. In case anyone is interested: https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Whose&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

Comment: PS - seriously not trying to be a pedant, it's clearly a matter of taste

Answer (score 2):

1  the room the door of which is green

2  the room whose door is green

The first construction is a bit clumsy. The second is shorter and much more practical. That's why the second way is replacing the first.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the second construction is newer than the first/becoming more common than the  first?

Comment: That is quite another question. But I admit an interesting one. But I never had the idea to look into  the historical side of this matter nor did I study the frequency of the two constructions today. But I take it for granted that the shorter one is more common.

Comment: It seemed to be implied in your answer ("the second way is replacing the first") so if you don't know, you might want to reword that part.

Comment: As I seldom read  the first constructon, but occasionally find  the second I think I may use the formulation that I chose.  By the way, what I write here is no professoral thesis. And I find you can formulate as carefully as you want you get a shot from some corner.

Comment: The room with the green door?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct. See also
http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/whose-for-inanimate-objects

According to grammar girl, whose is the only word we have to refer to inanimate antecedents.